# how to get square brackets with \SIrange{}{}{}?

Tags: siunitx, brackets

I'd like to get something like this: [-40 ; 80] °C

Instead I'm getting:

[image]

Below is a MWE. I've tried to include all necessary packages for `siunitx`, as written in its documentation; there are more, perhaps they are conflicting with the ones `siunitx` requires...

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, amsfonts, xfrac, mathpazo} %all maths
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{outlines}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label= \roman*)}
\setlist[enumerate,3]{label=\textbf{\alph*})}
\usepackage{siunitx}
 \sisetup{range-phrase = \ ;\ ,
          range-units  = brackets,
          list-units   = brackets}
\usepackage{listings} %useful for siunitex
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdfstartview=FitH} 
\usepackage[italian]{cleveref} 

\begin{document}
$\SIrange{-40}{80}{\celsius}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: For your example you just need the `siunitx` package. It does not need anything else. I guess you misunderstood Joseph Wright. He writes that you need these packages installed in order to compile his documentation. But you can just type `texdoc siunitx` in a terminal and get it nicely done shown in your pdf-reader.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The author of `siunitx` is English, so “bracket” doesn't mean the same as on the other side of the pond. By default, brackets are parentheses, but it's possible to customize them.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
  range-phrase = \ {;}\ ,
  range-units  = brackets,
  open-bracket = [,
  close-bracket= ],
}

\begin{document}
$\SIrange{-40}{80}{\celsius}$
\end{document}
```

The `{;}` trick makes for symmetric space on either side.

[image]

If you want to apply the square brackets only for `\SIrange`, then you can redefine the command to locally do the setting:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
  range-phrase = \ {;}\ ,
  range-units  = brackets,
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\RenewDocumentCommand \SIrange { O{} m m m } {
  \leavevmode
  \group_begin:
     \keys_set:nn { siunitx } { open-bracket = [,  close-bracket= ], #1}
     \__siunitx_range_unit:nnnn {#4} { open-bracket = [,  close-bracket= ], #1} {#2} {#3}
  \group_end:
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
$\SIrange{-40}{80}{\celsius}$

\SIlist[list-units = brackets]{2;4;6;8}{\tesla}

\num[bracket-negative-numbers]{-15673}

\num{1 \pm 2i e3}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: 'Bracket' is a generic term in UK English: 'parenthesis' is specific to `()` :-)

Comment: @JosephWright May I know how to enclose the unit itself with brackets?

Comment: Would you please explain what the backslashes in `range-phrase = \ {;}\ ,` are used for?

Comment: @Diaa “Space, semicolon, space”.

Answer (score 2):

The version shown by egreg is very elegant but also quite harsh to other brackets you might want to use. It's not clear from your question, if you would like to have the following behaviours, too:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
  range-phrase = \ {;}\ ,
  range-units  = brackets,
  open-bracket = [,
  close-bracket= ],
}

\begin{document}\noindent
\SIrange{-40}{80}{\celsius}\\
\SIlist[list-units = brackets]{2;4;6;8}{\tesla} \\
\num[bracket-negative-numbers]{-15673} \\
\num{1 \pm 2i e3} \\
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you really just want to change the behaviour of the range case shown in your question, I would recommend to redefine this command.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{scrartcl}    
\usepackage{siunitx}
\renewcommand{\SIrange}[3]{\lbrack\num{#1}\ {;}\ \num{#2}\rbrack\,\si{#3}}

\begin{document}\noindent
$\SIrange{-40}{80}{\celsius}$\\
\SIrange{-40}{80}{\celsius}
\end{document}
```

This also yields

[image]

but does not touch all the other cases.